# Using Global.asax to set/check session variable and redirect (for user testing)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add very simple, temporary security to my site.

I made a page at Home/UnderConstruction where people testing the site can enter a hard-coded password which will then set the "underconstruction" session variable to "false".

This is what I have so far, but it results in too many redirects:

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["underconstruction"] = "true";
    }

    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
                {
                    var underconstruction = HttpContext.Current.Session["underconstruction"];
                    if (underconstruction != null)
                    {
                        string oc = underconstruction.ToString();
                        if (oc != "false") Response.Redirect("~/Home/UnderConstruction");
                    }
                }

    }
```

Is this close to what I would need to do?

**Here is the code we got to work:**

**Controller Code for UnderConstruction View**

```
    public ViewResult UnderConstruction()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UnderConstruction(string ocp)
    {
        if (ocp == "mypassword")
        {
            Session["underconstruction"] = "false";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["beingredirected"] = "false";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Global.Asax**

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["underconstruction"] = "true";
        HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"] = "false";
    }


    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            bool uc = false;
            var underconstruction = HttpContext.Current.Session["underconstruction"];
            if (underconstruction != null)
            {
                uc = Boolean.Parse(underconstruction.ToString());
            }

            bool redirected = false;
            var beingredirected = HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"];
            if (beingredirected != null)
            {
                redirected = Boolean.Parse(beingredirected.ToString());
            }

            if (uc && !redirected)
            {
                if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"] = "true";
                    Response.Redirect("~/Home/UnderConstruction");
                }
                else if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
                {
                }

            }

            HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"] = "false";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it? That is where I would start

Comment: Yes, but like I said, it results in an endless loop.  I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Just a thought, but can you change your if statement to `if (oc == "true")` as you're not trimming or lower casing it for the comparison?

Comment: I still get the message "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome.  I'm presuming the same problem would happen in other browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is `~/Home/UnderConstruction` in a different website? If not, wont it always redirect because `oc` will always be true? ie - do you also need to add a check for the page you're requesting so you can bypass the redirect if already going to the `UnderConstruction` page?

**UPDATE**

Not sure if checking the page name is a great idea, but something like this might work:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["underconstruction"] = "true";
    HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"] = "false";
}

protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        bool uc = false;
        var underconstruction = HttpContext.Current.Session["underconstruction"];
        if (underconstruction != null)
        {
            uc = Boolean.Parse(underconstruction);
        }

        bool redirected = false;
        var beingredirected = HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"];
        if (beingredirected != null)
        {
            redirected = Boolean.Parse(beingredirected);
        }

        if (uc && !redirected)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"] = "true";
            Response.Redirect("~/Home/UnderConstruction");
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Session["beingredirected"] = "false";
    }
}
```

Note that I would clean that up, that example was to just give the general idea.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use roles as mentioned in the comments, then [this article from ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx) may help. Its a little more complicated, but has the added benefit of not introducing temporary code as the above solution will

Comment: New answer seems to help but it seems when I go to the page a second time without entering a password it lets me in.  It's almost there.  I'm looking into it and will post back soon.

Comment: @MightMuke,If I have understood it correctly then here you are hiding the original error.  Orginal error of "too many redirects" is because you are navigating to Underconstruction page on global.asax after calculating few conditions and setting the session. On next roundup, global asax will again go through the same cycle. There is no exit point. Session_Start event is not used for creating a session, it contains the logic which will happen when the session starts.

Comment: @CodeSpread Yep, more than likely. I was simply pointing out that unless a check was added to allow navigation to the under construction page, then you'd enter a redirect loop. My code certainly isn't pretty. By the sounds of it, I suspect you have a much better solution :)

Comment: @Mightymuke, Here the temporary security issue can be implemented by using web.config '<'roles'>' section.

Comment: @CodeSpread - agreed, assuming it can be implemented simply in their particular environment.

Comment: Mightymuke, I made some slight adjustments, since the .asax code was preventing to post from occurring (needed to set the underconstruction session variable).  Also had to reset the other session variable in the View.  I posted my changes above.  I couldn't have done it without your help.  Thanks.