# Session checking in all pages without a master page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

When I attended an interview, there was one question; `if there is no master page in an application then how we can check session in all pages`. I searched in internet and couldn't find an apt solution.

Please post the answer who knows... Reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can inherit your page class to a class which inherit base page class and has code to check session.

Comment: `Global.asax` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617421/using-global-asax-to-set-check-session-variable-and-redirect-for-user-testing

Comment: @SainPradeep-It will be helpful if u can provide a link.

Comment: @Kola-Global.asax runs on application start only right?

Comment: @TechDo there are different Method inside `Global` file. Which runs on different event. Like `Application Start`, `Seesion Start` ,`On Every Request` etc. [More Detail](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/what-is-use-of-globalasax-file-in.html)

Comment: please refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27165/Using-a-Custom-Base-Class-for-Security-and-Session